# Crear un array nuevo en bucle for JS

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy tratando de crear un array nuevo por cada vuelta que de un for.

```js
var route = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  route[i].push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lat());
  route[i].push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lng());

  console.log(route[i]);

}
```

Pero la consola me dice que es `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes hacer un push a un undefined:

```
var route = []; //array vacío

for (var i = 0, i < 5; i++) {
  //estás asumiendo que route[i] tiene un array
  //pero...
  console.log(route[i]); //undefined
  //fallaría
  //route[i].push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lat());
  //route[i].push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lng());

  //solución:
  let aux=[];
  aux.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lat());
  aux.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lng());
  route.push(aux);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo. Al final opte por hacerle push al array y en cada vuelta limpiarlo (rote = [ ]). Pero me servira de ayuda tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentando acceder a la posicion i de un array que no está inicializado.
Con inicializarlo se te resuelve el problema.

```
var route = [0];

for (var i = 0, i < 5; i++) {
                        route[i].push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lat());
                        route[i].push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i].lng());

console.log(route[i]);

                    }
```

Comment: Con eso no solucionas nada, estás creando un array con una posición que además tiene un número, no un array. Además, va a necesitar un array de 5 posiciones

Comment: En JS no defines el tamaño del array ni el tipo.
Lo único que hago es inicializar la primera posicion a 0, de manera que ya se puede acceder a la posición "i" e iterar sin problema.

Comment: `route=[0]` crea un array con un único elemento cuyo valor es `0`, un número